# 500 Internal Server Error using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

So my website keeps giving me a 500 Internal Server Error when I attempt to open my PHP file to write to the MySQL database

**HTML**

```
<div id="body">
<form action="index.php" method="post" />
  <input type="text" name="usertext" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

 define('DB_NAME', '****');
 define('DB_USER', '****');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
 define('DB_HOST', '****');

 $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

 if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
 }

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Cannot access' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error());
}

$value = $_POST['****'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO **** (****) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysqli_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}

mysqli_close();
?>
```

I'm still new to HTML and PHP, but I can't figure out what I did wrong even after hours of searching. My website keeps giving me that same error. I use goDaddy as a host if that helps at all.

Comment: Turn on error reporting - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script. A 500 Error usually means a Fatal PHP error. It'll probably be because you haven't passed your `DB_NAME` in your `mysqli_connect()` function. It should be: `mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);`

Comment: Offhand there is a mistake in the database select. Must be: `$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);`

Comment: Neither of those ended up working for me. It's still giving me the error page and nothing else. I don't know if goDaddy doesn't allow me to view the php error reports or what.

Comment: As @Darren said, a more detailed error report is required so as not to practice divination.

Comment: <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting('E_ALL');                             will display error.

Comment: as @Darren mentioned, you need to provide the db name in mysqli_connect and later if you want,you can use method to change db.

Comment: mysqli_error() ---> change to mysqli_error($link)

Comment: I tried the error message code but am still not receiving any messages

Comment: @AdamHartman You should check your apache error logs then, it'll be in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', '****');
define('DB_USER', '****');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
define('DB_HOST', '****');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Cannot access' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysqli_error($link));
}

$value = $_POST['****'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO **** (****) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

You've missed to user the $link variable when you were cheking for errors and running the query. The $link variable / connection have to be used everytime you're running something with mysqli_*, since it's the connection.
The mysqli_select_db were also made wrong, you have to define the connection first, then the name of the database.

Answer (score -1):

Most 500 errors are server-side errors.

There can be following probable reasons :

1. **Permission Error** : Check permission of files and folders. In most of those cases, an incorrect permission on a PHP and CGI script is to blame. The permission should be set at 755.
2. **PHP Timeout** : Timeout rules, or better error handling in your script, should help if this is the cause of the 500 error.
3. **Error in .htaccess** : Check if .htaccess is structured properly.

Comment: How do I check a file's permission exactly?

Comment: Open file manager in cpanel. You'll get Permissions as options. If you're working on local server just right click folder and check File permission

Comment: I tried it but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score -1):

also check if you have enabled the mysql extension in php.ini

Comment: Kindly share the code to enable the same.